# React JS Cannot read property 'keys' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, key

I am beginning to learn React through a tutorial, however I ran into this error when I ran the code that I created.

The error seems to be one that has to do with the framework of the languages. Perhaps with the version of Babel that I imported for the translation.

Does anyone know the actual situation and how to find a soulution.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.1/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/6.1.19/browser.js"></script>
    <title>ReactJs</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/babel">
        var HelloWorld = ReactDOM.createClass({
        render: function() {
        return <div>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <p>This is some text></p>
        </div>
        }
        });
        ReactDOM.render(<HelloWorld/>, document.body);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you have found the results yet, but I got the same error and found out it's the cdn version mismatch issues.

If you use these cdn's:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.29/browser.js"></script>
```

and change your

```
ReactDOM.render(<HelloWorld/>, document.body);
```

to

```
React.render(<HelloWorld/>, document.body);
```

it will work now.

Answer (score 1):

`babel-browser` is deprecated. use `babel-standalone` https://github.com/babel/babel-standalone instead:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

React.render has been deprecated since React 0.14 (released October 7, 2015):

https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html

I'd strongly recommend the awesome Create React App NPM module from Facebook, which creates React apps with no configuration, but still uses the latest ES6 and Babel features. Also it comes with hot reloading out of the box and has a build option, for creating a minified, bundled .js file ready for production.

https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app